# Using String Size to Declare Array Size in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

Lets say I have two string sizes sizeA and SizeB, can I use them both to create an array like the following:

```
    char str[sizeA+sizeB];
```

I want the array to be one dimensional and with size of both sizeA and sizeB combined. How would I do that correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: Show the declaration of `sizeA` and `sizeB`.

Comment: Is that array definition inside a code block, making the array local? Then, if the compiler/library supports it alloca may be your best bet (given typical string lengths).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's fine.

It's called a [variable-length array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and was added in C99.

If you intend to create an actual string in that array, you need to `+ 1` for the terminator.

If this is inside a function and you intend to return the new array, you must use heap allocation through `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a compiler that does not support C99, and `sizeA` and `sizeB` are not constant, you can not do that. You could either determine a size that will be big enough for all cases, or you can dynamically allocate the buffer with the correct size using `malloc`